# How can I get the current users permission groups?

Tags: c++, windows, permissions, qt4

I have a Qt/C++ project and an old VB6 project.

The user base might not have permissions to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE due to lack of administrator rights but I need to update a registry entry.

How can I get a list of the groups to which a user belongs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have this [is_admin](http://web.archive.org/web/20150324022053/http://win32.mvps.org/security/is_admin.html) program bookmarked. It's a good example of how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [NetGroupGetUsers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370430(VS.85).aspx) API.